# Exclude fields from updating

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've been searching high and low, but I can't find this.

I simply want to exclude certain fields (`__v`, `updatedAt`) from getting updated from the outside (by a HTML **PUT** request).

Of course there's always the possibility of deleting unwanted fields from the request body, but surely this can't be the preferred way?

Comment: insted can you send null in that cases whherever you need to exclude

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty yes, but that would still mean, that I'd have to edit the request body in the router. I would like to keep my router clean of stuff my schema should do. I solved it now by giving my model an attribute containing all fields that should not be updated. I then iterate over that in my router.. but I'd still prefer a built-in function.